# sendRedirect is not working

Tags: apache-felix, aem, day-cq

I am facing problem while developing filter with day CQ in my project. My code is working with requestDispatcher's forward method. But with response.sendRedirect(), it is not working.

```
if (servletRequest instanceof SlingHttpServletRequest) {
   HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
   HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
   String uri = httpRequest.getRequestURI();

   if(uri.startsWith("/content")){
    Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
    boolean found = false;
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        log.info("Cookies in filter: " + cookie.getName());
        if("LtpaToken2".equals(cookie.getName())){
            log.info("LTPA token found ");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
    else{
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
    }           
  }else{
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
  }

 log.info("Message URL ::"+httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
 log.info("URI ::"+uri);
}
```

So please resolve my issue , it is very appreciatable.

Regards
Narsi p

Comment: Do you need to cast SlingHttpServletRequest to HttpServletRequest ? SlingHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Can you provide the context for the above code?  What class/method is this in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Spring, but in JEE you can't really manipulate the response like that in a Filter. You will get an `IllegalStateException` when using `sendRedirect` or `sendError`.

My advice is to never use those abstractions. What you want to do is to specify a response header and close the request.

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", ""http://www.google.com");
return;
```